# Can I blend Future Perfect and future-in-the-past?

Tags: grammar

Can I blend Future Perfect and future-in-the-past? For example,

> He **would have served** the remainder of his term and leave office in 1990.

It may be confusing since the "would have" structure is also used in the 3rd type of conditionals so the sentence could be misinterpreted (not that he *did* serve it completely, but that he *could* serve it if some conditions were met but didn't, at least if the sentence didn't have the second half). The reason I don't want to simply use future-in-the-past is I want to stress that the action was completed.

Comment: Both verbs are in the same tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a way to mix and match like that.

You could have a counterfactual with "would have served... (would have) left" like this:

> If he had not been ousted, he would have continued in office.  He would have served the remainder of his term and left office in 1990.

Or you could describe the real outcome with "would serve... (would) leave" like this:

> His enemies had failed to oust him.  He would serve the remainer of his term and leave office in 1990.

Comment: Please elaborate. So you think I shouldn't use 'would have' in that sentence, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I do.  'Would have' carries too strong a suggestion of the unreal past (which isn't what you are trying to do), and the sentence feels incoherent with "would have served" in one half and "(would) leave office" in the second half.

Answer (score 0):

> He would have served the remainder of his term and leave office in
> 1990.

is the exact equal of this:

> He would have served the remainder of his term, and he **would have** leave office in
> 1990.

As you can see `would have leave` is not a known grammar structure in English.

You change it to

> He would have served the remainder of his term, and he **would have** **left** office in
> 1990.

or you can combine the two sentences with the `and` :

> He would have served the remainder of his term and left office in
> 1990.

Comment: 'Would have served' + 'would leave'. That's what I implied

Comment: Your verbs between the "and" should be parallel in their tenses so I think you can not connect "have served" and "leave" with an "and."

Answer (score 0):

**He would have [or could have] served the remainder of his term and left office in 1990**.

***would have or could have*** **goes with both verbs but you don't have to repeat it.**

Same idea: I **have seen** the movie and [have] **been** to the beach.

He **would have eaten** ice cream and [would have] **drunk** beer too!

There is no blending:
He would have served
he would have left

But: no need to repeat "would  have".

In compound verb phrases, there is no need to repeat the modals and auxiliaries. You only repeat the past particple.

Comment: Well, I didn't. I'm not sure why you underscored it so much

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev AND, if you meant: would have left and would leave, you need to write: would leave and not just leave.